# Give an example of a function $f$ for which $f$ is continuous nowhere but $|f|$ is continuous everywhere

Tags: calculus

> Give an example of a function $f$ for which $f$ is continuous nowhere but $|f|$ is continuous everywhere.

I am not sure how to find such an example. Naturally I would start with the definition of the limit: $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \quad |x-a| < \delta \quad \implies \quad |f(x)-L|<\epsilon $$ is never true but $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \quad |x-a| < \delta \quad \implies \quad ||f(x)|-L|<\epsilon $$ is always true. How do I go about constructing such a function?

Comment: $f(x)=1, x\in\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=-1$ for irrational $x$

Comment: @Svetoslav How do you prove it is not continuous?

Comment: Just use the definition of continuity and the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$: Let $x_0$ is arbitrary. For any $\delta$- neighbourhood of $x_0$ there are both rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: @user19405892, you may see the function mentioned by Svetoslav as a variant of the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function), the indicator function for rationals.

Comment: @Svetoslav Essentially the argument you are making is that we can't make $\epsilon$ very small, right?

Comment: Yes, it means that $\sup \limits_{|x-x_0|\leq \delta}{|f(x)-f(x_0)|}=2$ for any $\delta>0$

Comment: If you want, you can split the argument in 2 cases: 1) if $x_0\in\mathbb Q$ then $f(x_0)=1$. And if you suppose that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $\forall \epsilon>0\,\exists \delta>0:\,|f(x)-1|\leq \epsilon,\,\forall x:\,|x-x_0|\leq \delta$. But for $\epsilon =1$ for example, there is no such $\delta$. Analogously for if $x_0$ is irrational.